# How to generate and host node.js app from a pre-made one on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord, hosting

The title maybe a little confusing, so here is what I mean. I have a website where I can allow users to create discord bots, a node.js app basically, but I'm running into a problem. I have the node.js app (bot) saved in a folder on my computer, and for each bot a user creates on the website I want to generate a template of the app and change it's content based on the user's needs which then can be hosted to be online.

I just want to know how I can generate a template for this folder based on the user's needs, how it could be hosted on a service like Heroku, aws, etc., and what are some services/things that could make this process easier.

Here is an illustration to better show what I want to do:
[I'm not allowed to embed images, so link it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw6va.png)

I'm not asking for direct steps, just asking for suggestions because I'm kind of lost right now.
If you have a better way of doing this, I would be more than happy to hear about it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

1. Building a Docker-Image of your Node.js base app
2. Transfer the changes supplied by the user to a Dockerfile or such
3. Reference the base image in the Dockerfile as `FROM...`
4. Build & Push the images to a container registry
5. Use the customized images to host them in heroku/kubernetes/swarm etc.